# Java LibGDX moving animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I move Sprite fluently?I have tried in this way.

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor( 1F, 1F, 1F, 1F );
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

            batch.begin();
               mySprite.draw(batch);
               mySprite.setX(BladeAnimation.bladeFalling());
            batch.end();
}
```

I have changed `xPosition` with other function but the animation is not playing fluently.

Comment: You aren't even rendering it. You just set the position. This cannot be your real code.

Comment: yes that`s not real code, I forgot to write mySprite.draw(batch);

Comment: Show the real code... also how you are adjusting xPosition.

Comment: please give me your mail or facebook account I`ll send you the image of my code stackoverflow does not allow me to post it ,says your post is mostly code

Comment: Put it on pastebin.com or something silimar and link it here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Lx1NBHMh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the code that is changing the position in the render() method, other wise it changes only once. Unless if you are changing the position elsewhere. Show the code that changes the position to get a better answer

Comment: I call that function each time when I call setX function

Comment: Ok use Gdx.app.log(**put the x value here to see if its changing or not**)  . Or if thats not showing up in the log use System.out.println(**xvalue**)

Comment: it is changing and animation works but it isn`t playing fluently.

Comment: the issue might be that in bladeFallingPart1() you are using velocityYdown, whereas in all the others you are using velocityY. If you still can't figure it out, what you can do is post you project on github, send me the link, and i'll send you a fix it i can. Or you can tell me what you are trying to do and i can come up with the code and send it to you

Comment: it runs on Alcatel Snap and Desktop good but on Xperia X10 works slow.I think the reason is that Xperia x10 cant run 60fps

Comment: well there are a few things you can do to make it run a bit quicker. Are your textures in one pack or are they all separate assets. If so check this out :  https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker .  And try using these lines in the android launcher:  config.useCompass = false;
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.touchSleepTime = 50;

Comment: thank you)have you games for android in google play?

Comment: nah bro, i'm just a second year engineering student, just learnt this stuff off youtube. The biggest project i'm working on right now is not a game (https://www.behance.net/gallery/Aslant-Launcher-Concept/11752561)

Comment: Are you working alone on that project?I am only 15years old =D

Comment: Well Ilya Tsuprun designed it and i'm making it, so in terms of code I am. Good on you bro, wish i started coding earlier (about to turn 19, started 17)